# Shopware api, configuration group type also showing image on type picture

Tags: shopware

I am working with Shopware API. I have wrote code to update value from csv to shopware using api. My sample content is shows below.

```
            $configurationSet = [
                'name' => "Test set",
                'type'  =>  2,
                'groups' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Farbe',
                        'options' => [
                            "name" => "Red"
                         ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Größe',
                        'options' => [
                             'name' => 'XXL',
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            $variant['configuratorOptions'] = [
                ['group' => 'Farbe', 'option' => 'Red'],
                ['group' => 'Größe', 'option' => 'XXL']
            ];
```

When I update data values are saving. But size shows images over it. How can I fix this by api? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Please see the screen shot.[image]

Comment: "But size shows images over it" - I don't get this sentence. Maybe you could translate your question with deepl.com or something like that?

Comment: Sorry for the language. Please see the pic. In that, the second configuration group, Größe should show the size of the item. Like Small, Large, XL. In my situation, the image is mapping towards every configuration options. I fixed this situation by running query in the database. But I would like to know the issue in my importing code. I will edit the question and share full code.